# Can pseudo-legendary Pokémon mega evolve?

Tags: pokemon

Ash recently caught Dragonite which is a pseudo-legendary Pokémon. We have not seen any pseudo-legendary Pokémon mega evolution until now. so Can pseudo-legendary Pokémon mega evolve?

Comment: Are you asking for anime appearances of these mega evolutions? Because the wiki clearly lists which of them have Mega evolutions

Comment: @TheGamer007  I will look for a reliable source and reference that is fine.

Comment: it is fan-made not reliable. https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Mega_Evolution

Answer (score 0):

Four of the Pokemon that fall under the unofficial category of pseudo-legendary can mega evolve, one of which Ash would have if the dingus would just evolve it, those four being: Tyrantitar, Metagross, Salamence and Garchomp.